# PHP how to display user data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the unique user who is logged in and then store it into a table in my database for example if I was logged in as James i want to display James' data from the database and store his id into another table.from my understanding the $_SESSION['login_user']; should return the unique users username.

when ever I run I get this error this is the output:

Notice: Undefined index: login_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\bid.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\bid.php on line 8
Thank You For Contacting Us

login.php

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE email_adress = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['customer_id'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

 if($count >= 1) {
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

     header("location: index2.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
   }
?>
```

bid.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
require 'config.php';
//include "job.php" 
$jobid    = $_POST['job_id'];
$bid    = $_POST['bid'];
bidderid = $SESSION['username']
echo "$jobid";






$query   = "INSERT into bid (bid_amount,job_id) VALUES('" . $bid . "','" . $jobid . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

$conn->close();

 ?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email_adress from customer where email_adress = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['email_adress'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
      header("location:login.php");
   }
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your `login_user` most likely doesn't exist yet in your session.

You have a type at: `bidderid = $SESSION['username']`.

Comment: do i need to somehow add something in session setting username as the id of user from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

login.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // session should start here

   include("config.php");


   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE email_adress = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";

      $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; // you missed a semi colon

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['customer_id'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

 if($count >= 1) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; // $myusername contains username of this user

     $_SESSION['login_data'] = $row; // $row contains user record from the db. including customer_id etc..


     header("location: index2.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
  }
   }
?>
```

Now if it's a success $_SESSION['login_user'] would be available in bid.php and every other pages.

2. In session.php, please revert to these.

   ```
     <?php
      session_start(); 
      // this should be called first before including external files 
      include('config.php');

      $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

      $ses_sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select email_adress from customer where email_adress = '$user_check' ");

      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

      $login_session = $row['email_adress'];

      if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
         header("location:login.php");
      }
   ?>
   ```
3. in bid.php please refer to this.

   ```
        $bidderid = $_SESSION['login_user']->username or  $_SESSION['login_user']['username']
   ```

Hope this helps.. Happy coding

Comment: hey i edited to show my login.php, i try to set $session username but some reason I am still getting the same error

Comment: ok you can't use a local variable in regards to the global variable $_SESSION, you made that mistake also in your bid.php

please use $_SESSION instead

Comment: so it should be $_SESSION['username']

Comment: you can paste in your login.php so i can help re-modify if needed.

Comment: the session login user is kind of confusing me i updated my code above and what im trying to do in login.php is set the $SESSION[username] equal to $username but i still seem to be getting errors